# Where are the Special Function Registers located? (Atmega 328)

Tags: arduino-uno

I'd like to program my Arduino using Assembler. We have to learn this at college. 
The problem is that I can find a documentation for the instruction set but I can't find the Special Function Registers.

Something like this would be great or similar to make a sheet like this by myself.

Comment: http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/AVR?

Comment: Well at least there is "AVR" in the heading. But not more... I know this site and I couldn't find what I search. I have shown an example. Where can I find something like this??

Comment: Read the whole thing, I think it might be pertinent. As they say, "Do not judge the book by its cover!".

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation This is what I found (some time ago). But it seems that this is only relevant for the pins. I need "direct" access to the whole atmega not through c functions.

Comment: All the registers are given in great detail in the datasheet for the chip.

Comment: [Chapter 36](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf#612)

Comment: Note that C functions already do access the "whole Atmega", you don't need assembly to do that. The only way to do what you want is to read the whole datasheet from the start and ensure you understand it (it may take several reads until you really udnerstand it, this is never an easy read for anyone). From the lack of details in your question, this is the only good advice you'll be able to get.

Comment: The [Port Registers Arduino tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/PortManipulation) really shows you the most “direct” way to access the SFRs. If you write something like `PORTB |= bit(PB5);` and disassemble the resulting binary, you will see the compiler translates that statement into a single `sbi` machine instruction.

Answer (score 2):

There are several options for programming the AVR in assembly, but since
you have an Arduino and the Arduino IDE bundles the gcc toolchain, using
this toolchain is probably the easiest way. Besides, if you learn
assembly in the GNU syntax, you will be able to use it together with C++
and the Arduino libraries.

The gnu compiler will run through the C preprocessor any assembly
program having the `.S` extension (in uppercase). You would then start
your program with

```
#include <avr/io.h>
```

in order to get all the SFR definitions from avr-libc. That include file
is intended to work both in C and in assembly. The SFRs so declared
should be considered as opaque identifiers. To get their addresses, you
should use the macros `_SFR_IO_ADDR()` or `_SFR_MEM_ADDR()`. I
personally find those names too cumbersome to type, so I tend to
`define` my own shortcuts.

Just to get you started, here is a minimal “blinky” program in assembly
for the Arduino Uno (ATmega328P with the LED on PB5):

```
; Blinky in assembly.

#include <avr/io.h>
#define io(reg) _SFR_IO_ADDR(reg)

.global main
main:
    sbi io(DDRB), PB5  ; PB5 as output
0:  sbi io(PINB), PB5  ; toggle PB5

    ; delay 16 * 65536 * 5 cycles ~ 0.31 s
    ldi  r26, 16
1:  sbiw r24, 1
    sbci r26, 0
    brne 1b

    rjmp 0b ; restart
```

Answer (score 1):

> Where are the Special Function Registers located? (Atmega 328)

Please see Chap. 36 Register Summary, pp. 612, in 
http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-8271-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega48A-48PA-88A-88PA-168A-168PA-328-328P_datasheet_Complete.pdf

The registers are available "by name" in the AVR IO header files.

Cheers!